# deploy jar on windows server with jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, executable-jar

I have a maven built jar file which could be run as a server. I want to use jenkins-pipeline to deploy this jar file onto my windows 2016 server. I started with a **freestyle** jenkins job, with "Execute Windows batch" configuration:

`set BUILD_ID=DontKillMe
start java -jar MyServer.jar`

The java process successfully spawned on my windows 2016 server.

When I turned to use jenkins pipeline script with same batch commands, it's not as expected -- the process which should contain `java -jar MyServer.jar` was never spawned.
The pipeline script I wrote is:

`bat '''
set BUILD_ID=DontKillMe
start java -jar MyServer.jar
'''`

The reason I want to have jar starts running in another process is that it could release current jenkins build to following steps.

Could anyone please help with a solution? As long as I can spawn up the java process from batch command in jenkins pipeline (better with no parent process), I would be really grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, seems like jenkins is trying to abandon old jenkins users like me, here's the solution provided by jenkins pipeline:

```
withEnv(['JENKINS_NODE_COOKIE=DontKillMe']) {
    bat "start java -jar MyServer.jar"
}
```